# scrapy reading urls from a txt file fail

Tags: python, scrapy

This is how the txt file looks like, and I opened it from jupiter notebook. Notice that I changed the name of the links in the result for obvious reason.
input-----------------------------

with open('...\j.txt', 'r')as f:
    data = f.readlines()

print(data[0])
print(type(data))

output---------------------------------

['https://www.example.com/191186976.html', 'https://www.example.com/191187171.html']

Now I wrote these in my scrapy script, it didn't go for the links when I ran it. Instead it shows: ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests.

class abc(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "abc_article"

```
with open('j.txt' ,'r')as f4:
    url_c = f4.readlines()

u = url_c[0]    
start_urls = u
```

And if I wrote u = ['example.html', 'example.html'] starting_url = u then it works perfectly fine. I'm new to scrapy so I'd like to ask what is the problem here? Is it the reading method or something else I didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: Please, format your code correctly. Also, you should be using [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) instead of `start_urls` if you are reading from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going in the right direction.

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
#import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = []
with open('C:\\your_path_here\\test.csv','r') as csvf: # Open file in read mode
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        contents.append(url) # Add each url to list contents

for url in contents:  # Parse through each url in the list.
    page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```